# Cancel all changes to a list and revert list items to original positions.

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there a way to cancel all changes from the sortable list? Say I have a list:

- List 1
- List 2
- List 3
- List 4

Then I move List 1 to the bottom:

- List 2
- List 3
- List 4
- List 1

Then move List 4 to the top:

- List 4
- List 2
- List 3
- List 1

Then I decided to 'cancel' all the changes and return all lists to their original positions. How can I do that? I tried using `cancel` method like `$("#sortable).sortable("cancel");`
but this only cancel the recent sort, returning List 4 under List 3.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to save the original order and retrieve it any time you need?

Comment: Hi @SaifHamed. Thanks but I don't have any idea how to do that using jquery. Perhaps you can enlighten me. :)

Comment: That's not possible. However you can use a work around have two sortable list, one hidden and other visible. If use clicks cancel, hide the existing div and show the hidden div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the original order in the beginning with

```
var origOrder = $('#sortable').find('li');
```

Then later when you want cancel the changes, just call

```
$('#sortable').html(origOrder);
```